# Dask: Is there a way to get each partition's ID from within a task so I can do something different within the task f

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to use `dask` for a set of text data I have. The text data is to be partitioned into 4 parts. I would like to get the partition ID from within the task so that something slightly different would be done depending on the partition. I wonder if there is a way to do it (as shown in the pseudo-code below).

```
def task(df, partition_id):
    if partition_id == 1:
        #do something
    elif partition_id == 2:
        #do something else
    elif partition_id == 3:
        #do something else
    else:
        #do something else.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the `.to_delayed` function to get out a bunch of Dask Delayed objects.  You can then do whatever you want to with them individually, and then convert back to a Dask dataframe with `dd.from_delayed`.

Here is a maybe useful doc page: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html